# How to combine different matries acording to their row names?

Tags: r, join, dataframe, rows

Let's say I have matrix A:

```
rows.names  Value
----------------
man         NA
woman       NA
girl        NA
boy         NA
cat         NA
dog         NA
```

and some more matrices (B, C, D, etc) like the following:

```
rows.names  V1
--------------
woman       3
dog         5


rows.names  V2
--------------
man         4
woman       7
cat         6

rows.names  V3
---------------
boy         17
cat         10
dog         1
```

And I want to join those 4 according to row.names (replacing the missing data with NAs):

```
row.names   Value   V1   V2   V3
--------------------------------
man         NA      NA   4    NA
woman       NA      3    7    NA
girl        NA      NA   NA   NA
boy         NA      NA   NA   17
cat         NA      NA   6    10
dog         NA      5    NA   1
```

How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title says "matrices" but your question is tagged `data.frame`, so here's an approach assuming you're dealing with `data.frame`s:

```
df1 <- data.frame(rn = c("man", "woman", "girl", "boy", "cat", "dog"), 
                  Value = NA)
df2 <- data.frame(rn = c("woman", "dog"), V1 = c(3, 5))
df3 <- data.frame(rn = c("man", "woman", "cat"), V2 = c(4, 7, 6))
df4 <- data.frame(rn = c("boy", "cat", "dog"), V3 = c(17, 10, 1))

library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d")), id.vars = "rn"), 
      rn ~ variable, value.var = "value")
#      rn Value V1 V2 V3
# 1   boy    NA NA NA 17
# 2   cat    NA NA  6 10
# 3   dog    NA  5 NA  1
# 4  girl    NA NA NA NA
# 5   man    NA NA  4 NA
# 6 woman    NA  3  7 NA
```

---

The general idea is to use `mget` to capture all of the relevant objects in a `list` (you can do this manually too, of course). Then, make use of the `list` method for `melt` to combine everything into a "long" `data.frame`. This can then easily be reshaped using `dcast`.

---

The approach is similar (maybe even easier) if you have matrices:

```
m1 <- `rownames<-`(as.matrix(df1[-1]), df1[[1]])
m2 <- `rownames<-`(as.matrix(df2[-1]), df2[[1]])
m3 <- `rownames<-`(as.matrix(df3[-1]), df3[[1]])
m4 <- `rownames<-`(as.matrix(df4[-1]), df4[[1]])

dcast(melt(mget(ls(pattern = "m\\d"))), Var1 ~ Var2, value.var = "value")
#    Var1 Value V1 V2 V3
# 1   man    NA NA  4 NA
# 2 woman    NA  3  7 NA
# 3  girl    NA NA NA NA
# 4   boy    NA NA NA 17
# 5   cat    NA NA  6 10
# 6   dog    NA  5 NA  1
```

Comment: Thanks! I even seem to understand it :).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this will work. Just match the row names with the Value matrix and then replace with a subset.  `vapply` will simplify it to a matrix that we can `cbind` with the main matrix.

```
mlist <- list(m2, m3, m4)

newPart <- vapply(mlist, function(x) {
        x[match(rownames(m1), rownames(x))]
    }, numeric(nrow(m1)))

cbind(m1, provideDimnames(newPart))
#       Value  A  B  C
# man      NA NA  4 NA
# woman    NA  3  7 NA
# girl     NA NA NA NA
# boy      NA NA NA 17
# cat      NA NA  6 10
# dog      NA  5 NA  1
```

Comment: I was thinking about `match`, but it wasn't clear if the first matrix would necessarily contain all of the rownames. So, I figured I would go the more predictable route. (+1)

Comment: @AnandaMahto - another nice trick I picked up that creates `NA`s easily is `replace`.  You can replace one NA with more than one things and NAs are filled in the gaps. `replace(NA, c(2,5,6,9,10), LETTERS[1:5])`

Comment: The only drawback is possibly not getting the desired length